# Не отправляется запрос на сервер с web dart приложения, как исправить?

Tags: запрос, https, flutter, dart, cloudflare

Недавно я изменил name записи моего домена и сервер стал загружаться через Cloudflare. Хостинг находится на 000webhost. До переноса на Cloudflare запросы на другой сервер удавалось отправлять с помощью библиотеки Dio для Dart. Теперь приложение выдает ошибку соединения. Как решить эту проблему, думаю она решается где то в настройках Cloudflare. Сайт greente.uz

Comment: Возможно у вас dns обновляются, это может проходить до двух дней.

Comment: Думаю все же проблема в исполнении Js на сайте из-за перенаправления через Cloudflare

Comment: А вы пробовали делать запрос через postman или curl?

Comment: post запрос на сервер отправляется и приходит ответ если делать это локально или с мобильного приложения, проблема именно в Cloudflare. он блокирует запрос по url. е могу разобраться с ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была именно в соединении HTTPS, если подключаться по HTTP все работает. Проблема была решена установкой SSL сертификата на конечный сервер.